# Como puedo sumar datos de en tablas relacionadas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

me gustaría que me puedan guiar o colaborar con esto que estoy intentando hacer.

Tengo estas 3 tablas relacionadas:

```
Create table Producto(
    id bigint primary key,
    NombreProducto varchar(90) not null,
    DescripcionPorducto varchar(90) not null,
    Precio float not null
)

Create table Pedido(
    id bigint primary key,
    FechaPedido datetime not null,
    EstadoPedido integer not null default(1),
    idCliente bigint references Cliente(id)
)

Create table DetallePedido(
    idPedido bigint  references Pedido(id),
    idProducto bigint  references Producto(id),
    primary key (idPedido, idProducto),
    Cantidad float not null, 
    PrecioCompra float not null
)
```

En la tabla `producto` cuento con los campos de `id`, `nombreproducto`, `descripcion` y `precio`, en el puedo hacer un `insert`, `update` y `delete`, ahí todo bien; mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo insertar datos en la tabla `DetallePedido` que al insertar me sume el precio total en `PrecioCompra`?

Por ejemplo, en la tabla `producto` tengo los datos:

```
id = 1
NombreProducto = Laptop
Descripcion = HP
Precio = 2000
```

En la tabla DetallePedido:

```
idPedido = 1
idProducto = 1
Cantidad = 2
PrecioCompra = (En este campo necesito que me sume y me inserte 4000 porque en cantidad hay 2 productos que se esta comprando.
```

Espero me puedan guiar o colaborar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! se podria hacer con un trigger.. pero en donde estan ingresando los datos, no saben ya esos valores?

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer lo que quieres hacer es utilizar información que está en un tabla (producto) para usar al insertar un nuevo registro en otra (DetallePedido).

Lo que deberías hacer es buscar el precio del producto primero con un SELECT y luego utilizar dicha información en el INSERT.

Existe la posibilidad de hacer un INSERT a partir de un SELECT (como muestro a continuación), pero no creo que sea adecuado para este caso.

```
INSERT INTO DetallePedido (idPedido, idProducto, Cantidad, PrecioCompra)
SELECT 1, 1, 2, 2 * Precio
FROM Producto
WHERE id = 1;
```